# Create a specific county map of a california state using Highcharts. For ex: Sacramento county

Tags: highcharts, maps

I am working with highcharts for the first time and trying to create a specific county map of california state. FOr ex. Sacramento county. I am able to produce california county map, but when i change a county from the dropdown, i want to produce that specific county map only and not all the counties of california state. Is it possible? Below is my code that I've worked on so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>California County Map</title>
    <!-- Include Highcharts library and modules -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-ca-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="ca-map" style="height: 600px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

    <script>
        (async () => {

            const topology = await fetch(
                "https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-ca-all.topo.json"
            ).then(response => response.json());

            const data = [
                ["us-ca-083", 10], ["us-ca-111", 11], ["us-ca-071", 12],
                ["us-ca-115", 13], ["us-ca-101", 14], ["us-ca-031", 15],
                ["us-ca-053", 16], ["us-ca-057", 17], ["us-ca-059", 18],
                ["us-ca-065", 19], ["us-ca-073", 20], ["us-ca-041", 21],
                ["us-ca-075", 22], ["us-ca-095", 23], ["us-ca-097", 24],
                ["us-ca-055", 25], ["us-ca-013", 26], ["us-ca-009", 27],
                ["us-ca-077", 28], ["us-ca-035", 29], ["us-ca-091", 30],
                ["us-ca-067", 31], ["us-ca-017", 32], ["us-ca-099", 33],
                ["us-ca-061", 34], ["us-ca-043", 35], ["us-ca-063", 36],
                ["us-ca-049", 37], ["us-ca-089", 38], ["us-ca-109", 39],
                ["us-ca-039", 40], ["us-ca-003", 41], ["us-ca-069", 42],
                ["us-ca-047", 43], ["us-ca-079", 44], ["us-ca-011", 45],
                ["us-ca-007", 46], ["us-ca-081", 47], ["us-ca-087", 48],
                ["us-ca-085", 49], ["us-ca-029", 50], ["us-ca-005", 51],
                ["us-ca-113", 52], ["us-ca-033", 53], ["us-ca-045", 54],
                ["us-ca-103", 55], ["us-ca-023", 56], ["us-ca-093", 57],
                ["us-ca-027", 58], ["us-ca-001", 59], ["us-ca-037", 60],
                ["us-ca-025", 61], ["us-ca-021", 62], ["us-ca-107", 63],
                ["us-ca-019", 64], ["us-ca-015", 65], ["us-ca-105", 66],
                ["us-ca-051", 67]
            ];

            const initialMarkerData = [];

            // Create the chart

            chart = Highcharts.mapChart("ca-map", {
                chart: {
                    map: topology,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                mapNavigation: {
                    enabled: true,
                    buttonOptions: {
                        verticalAlign: "bottom"
                    }
                },

                title: {
                    text: undefined
                },

                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    mappoint: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    data: data,
                    name: "County",
                    color: "#609DCF",
                    allowPointSelect: false, // true
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            color: "#609DCF"
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: "{point.name}"
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: "mappoint",
                    name: "Event",
                    data: initialMarkerData,
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: "{point.name}"
                    }
                }],
            });
        })();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve the functionality you're looking for in Highcharts. You can for example zoom to the selected point and hide the other ones.

```
document.getElementById('selectSacramento').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const points = chart.series[0].points;
  const thePoint = points.find(point => point.name === 'Sacramento');

  points.forEach(point => {
    if (point !== thePoint) {
      point.graphic.hide();
    }
  });

  thePoint.zoomTo();
  chart.mapZoom(1.3);
});

document.getElementById('zoomOut').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const points = chart.series[0].points;

  points.forEach(point => {
    point.graphic.show();
  });

  chart.zoomOut();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/et7q3oz8/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#zoomOut

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

Comment: thanks a ton! this is exactly what I was looking for. adjusted the code according to my need as I wanted it on the change of select dropdown of counties. learned a thing today. thanks again!